# Dibujar figuras geométricas en Matlab

Tags: matlab

Estoy intentando dibujar figuras geométricas con Matlab. Resulta fácil hacerlas vértice a vértice, pero lo que yo querría es encontrar una forma para dibujarlas 'lado a lado', esto es, poder cambiar a placer el color de cada lado si se cumple una determinada condición.

¿Alguien sabe cómo hacer esto posible?

Muchas gracias de antemano, y que tengáis buena semana.

Comment: Hola amigo, He verificado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask], Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar hold on al plotear cada tramo y ahí elegir el color.

```
x = [0,0;1,0;1,1;0,1;0,0];
lado_derecho = 'g';
lado_izquierdo = 'y';

figure;
hold on,
plot(x(:,1),x(:,2),'r');
plot(x(2:3,1),x(2:3,2),lado_derecho);
plot(x(4:5,1),x(4:5,2),lado_izquierdo);
```